# Output The Contents Of A Pivot / Linking Table In A Nested While Loop - MySQL / PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, nested

I have a situation where I'm trying to output the contents of a MySQL pivot/linking table from a many-to-many relationship with PHP.

In the code below I have a series of boards that will contain images. The actual board previews are outputted with the first block of PHP, but inside this I need a nested while loop that outputs the images themselves.

The pivot/linking table is called `boards_images` has two columns `board_id` and `image_id` and these are both foreign keys to the `boards` table and `images` table. A representation of the tables is given below the main code below.

Because some boards will have an image that is already on other boards I obviously need some type of conditional logic that outputs the image when the related board is present.

Each board preview will only show four images so I will need need to add a `LIMIT 4` clause to the MySQL

**My Question**

What is the best way to approach this, do I:

a) Need to do two database calls one in the parent while loop and one in the nested while loop, or do I need to get all of the info from the MySQL database in the parent while loop with a multiple JOIN?

b) How do I actually output the content of the pivot/linking table? I can't seem to get my head around how to do this.

```
<?php 

    // $db_id is a variable created from a user login $_SESSION value

    $sql = "SELECT boards.board_id, boards.board_name, users.user_id 
    FROM boards
    JOIN users ON boards.user_id = users.user_id 
    WHERE users.user_id = :user_id
    ORDER BY boards.board_id DESC";

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> execute([
        ':user_id' => $db_id
    ]);
    
    // parent while loop that outputs the board name

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $dbBoardname = htmlspecialchars($row['board_name']);
?>
    <div class="board-component">
        <h2><?= $dbBoardname; ?></a></h2>

        <?php

            // --- NESTED INNER WHILE LOOP

            $SQL2 = "SELECT boards_images.board_id, boards_images.image_id, images.filename
            FROM boards_images
            JOIN images ON boards_images.image_id = images.image_id
            WHERE boards_images.board_id = :board_id
            LIMIT 4";

            $stmt2 = $connection->prepare($SQL2);
            $stmt2 -> execute([
                ':board_id' => $dbBoardId
            ]);

            while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()) {          
                $dbImageId = htmlspecialchars($row['image_id']);
                $dbImageFilename = htmlspecialchars($row['filename']);
            ?>
                
             <img src='<?= $wwwRoot . "/images-lib/{$dbImageFilename}" ?>' >

        <?php } ?> <!-- end of nested while loop -->
    </div>
<?php } ?> <!-- end of parent while loop -->
```

**Representation of the Tables**

```
// 'fk' stands for foreign key

// BOARDS_IMAGES LINKING / PIVOT TABLE
+----------------+----------------+
|  board_id (fk) | image_id (fk)  |
+----------------+----------------+
|  1             |  23            |         
|  1             |  106           |
|  1             |  55            |
|  1             |  22            |
+----------------+----------------+

// BOARDS TABLE
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|  board_id   |  board_name  |  user_id (fk) |
----------------------------------------------
|  1          |  London      |  21           |
|  2          |  France      |  21           |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+

// IMAGES TABLE
+-------------+--------------------+---------------+
|  image_id   |  filename          | user_id (fk)  |
---------------------------------------------------+
|  23         |  BigBen.jpeg       | 21            |
|  106        |  TowerBridge.jpeg  | 21            |
|  55         |  TheMall.jpg       | 21            |
|  22         |  BuckPalace.jpg    | 21            |
+-------------+--------------------+---------------+

// USERS TABLE
+-----------------+----------------+
|  user_id        |  username      |
+-----------------+----------------+
|   21            |  johndoe       |         
+-----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Well, you first need to fetch the images that belong to that board. And then just loop over them the same way you do with the boards I suppose?

Comment: @geertjanknapen but how do I have it so the images are output in relation to the specific `board_id ` they are related to from the linking table?

Comment: @geertjanknapen I've added the code I was using that wasn't working on the nested while loop.

Comment: I am lost in your verbiage and example.  Are these 3 statements correct?  board :: image is many-to-many; each board belongs to one user; each image belongs to one user

Comment: @RickJames yes those 3 statements are correct.

Comment: *"that wasn't working"* You should be more specific. What isn't working?

Comment: Your code adds an extension to file names but they already have one.

Comment: @Olivier - I've removed that. It was where I was simplifying the code and mistakenly left it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) Need to do two database calls one in the parent while loop and one
> in the nested while loop, or do I need to get all of the info from the
> MySQL database in the parent while loop with a multiple JOIN?

You can do one query to get all the data necessary, we can limit the number of images displayed in php, and the join to the users table isn't needed because you have the FK in the boards table:

```
SELECT boards.board_name, images.filename
FROM boards
INNER JOIN boards_images on boards_images.board_id = boards.board_id
INNER JOIN images        on boards_images.image_id = images.image_id
WHERE boards.user_id = :user_id
```

> b) How do I actually output the content of the pivot/linking table? I
> can't seem to get my head around how to do this.

With the output of the above query resulting in something like:

```
board_name | filename
-------------------------------
London     |  BigBen.jpeg     
London     |  TowerBridge.jpeg
London     |  TheMall.jpg     
London     |  BuckPalace.jpg 
France     |  BigBen.jpeg     
France     |  TowerBridge.jpeg
France     |  TheMall.jpg     
France     |  BuckPalace.jpg
```

Your php loop could look something like this:

```
<?php 

    // $db_id is a variable created from a user login $_SESSION value

    $sql = "SELECT boards.board_name, images.filename
            FROM boards
            INNER JOIN boards_images on boards_images.board_id = boards.board_id
            INNER JOIN images        on boards_images.image_id = images.image_id
            WHERE boards.user_id = :user_id";

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> execute([
        ':user_id' => $db_id
    ]);

$dbBoardname_last = '';
$imgcount = 0;
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   $dbBoardname = htmlspecialchars($row['board_name']);
   $dbImageFile = "$wwwRoot/images-lib/" . htmlspecialchars($row['filename']);
    
    //if the boardname is the same as the previous row only add images. 
   if($dbBoardname != $dbBoardname_last) 
   {
    //reset the image count for new boards
     $imgcount = 0;
     echo "<div class=\"board-component\"><h2>$dbBoardname</a></h2>";
   }
   
   //By counting the images within the loop we can avoid using multiple or nested queries to the DB 
   if($imgcount < 4) { 
    echo "<img src=\"$dbImageFile\">";
   }
   $imgcount++; 
   
   if($dbBoardname != $dbBoardname_last) 
   {
     echo '</div>';
   } 
    //record the last board_name to check if a new board element should be created
   $dbBoardname_last = $dbBoardname;
 }
?>
```

Note: hopefully this code works as you intended but long term I think best practice would be to parse the SQL output into a JSON object and iterate over that instead, the code might come out cleaner

Comment: Hi @Simeononon - thanks for taking the time to answer. In the initial MySQL you select `filename` from the `boards` table, but there is now `filename` in the boards table?

Comment: Hi @Emmy, filename is being selected from the images table that is joined to the boards table, I've updated the code to reflect this

Comment: Hi @Simeononon I suggested a couple of edits to the answer and realised one of those edits isn't correct (it's currently pending edit review), namely the `   if($imgcount <= 4)` should indeed remain as ` if($imgcount < 4)`. It's very nearly working but if you accept or refuse the changes I can explain what is happening.

Comment: Why is boards.board_id required in the select statement? It's not used in the page at all, I've fixed the missing semicolon though- well spotted

Comment: apologies, it's used on the more complex version of the code. Yes please ignore. It was a manic day yesterday.

Comment: No worries, would you like me to include board_id in the query above? And is it working as intended?

Comment: There was an issue in terms of the closing div would wrap around the first image and then the other three images would follow that. The was because the condition for closing the board component div was the same as the condition for starting a new div but I managed to get this fixed. Because you got the closest to what I needed I think it's only correct that I give you the bounty.

Comment: Ah yes I didn't see that, did you get it to work by adding the image count to the last conditional?

Answer (score 0):

The approach of running a query, looping the results and for each result, running another query is a suboptimal approach, but it works. You may want to try that out, because it's simple and it is very much possible that the performance issues you are worried about would never materialize, kindly read this: https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/

The disadvantage, of course, is that, instead of running a single command, you run n + 1 command (assuming that the number of boards is n). Queries are costly, so, if you already encountered some performance issues related to this, or you want to write very performant code, then you can:

- write a single query
- the `FORM` clause's first table would be `boards`
- `LEFT JOIN` `boards_images` and `images`, with the appropriate criteria
- the resulting record would contain the `boards` and `images` data, defaulting to `null` if there are not enough matches

```
SELECT ...
FROM boards
JOIN users
ON boards.user_id = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN boards_images bi1
ON boards.board_id = bi1.board_id
LEFT JOIN images i1
ON bi1.image_id = i1.image_id
LEFT JOIN boards_images bi2
ON boards.board_id = bi2.board_id AND bi2.board_id NOT IN (bi1.board_id)
LEFT JOIN images i2
ON bi2.image_id = i2.image_id
LEFT JOIN boards_images bi3
ON boards.board_id = bi3.board_id AND bi3.board_id NOT IN (bi1.board_id, bi2.board_id)
LEFT JOIN images i3
ON bi3.image_id = i3.image_id
LEFT JOIN boards_images bi4
ON boards.board_id = bi4.board_id AND bi4.board_id NOT IN (bi1.board_id, bi2.board_id, bi3.board_id)
WHERE users.user_id = :user_id
```

You loop the records returned and use the returned values. I have left out the `SELECT` clause's content for you to fill it, you will need boards and images data there, with the images data columns ideally suffixed by the image index, so you can iterate the index and build the column names inside the loop.